# mysqli_real_escape_string runs the script

Tags: php

Just wanted to test **mysqli_real_escape_string**.
I was expecting the script embedded in **$string** to not work. However I  can see the alert message.

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "test_db";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $string = "<script>alert('This is script from php')</script>";
    echo mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$string);
?>
```

As far as I know that **mysqli_real_escape_string** should stop the script from execution.
Is there a better way. I know about the prepared statements .. anything apart from that I shoud do?

** NOT SIMILIAR AS [This one](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php) **

Comment: [From the docs](https://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp): "The function escapes special characters in a string **for use in an SQL query**". This does mean it will strip HTML tags. For that, you should look at [`strip_tags`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

Comment: @MattClark thats not correct, this function doesn't strip HTML tags, it just escapes the special characters to prevent a SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) is used to prevent SQL Injection .

what you want to do is preventing XSS because the `<script>` tag so you should use

`htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')`

Comment: real_escape_string should not be used to prevent SQL injection. This is not what it's for.

Comment: its not a good way to prevent SQL Injection with mysqli_real_escape_string . but it does prevent SQL Injection . always the best way is prepared statement .